# disable maven download progress indication

Tags: maven, logging

In our company in the CI machines maven local repository is purged before every build. As result my build logs always have a bunch of noise like this

```
Downloading: http://.../artifactory/repo/com/codahale/metrics/metrics-core/3.0.1/metrics-core-3.0.1.jar
4/2122 KB   
8/2122 KB   
12/2122 KB   
16/2122 KB   
18/2122 KB   
18/2122 KB   4/480 KB   
18/2122 KB   8/480 KB   
18/2122 KB   12/480 KB   
18/2122 KB   16/480 KB   
18/2122 KB   16/480 KB   4/1181 KB   
18/2122 KB   16/480 KB   8/1181 KB   
18/2122 KB   16/480 KB   12/1181 KB
```

Is there an option I to be able to disable the download progress indication?

Answer (score 309, accepted):

`mvn -B ..` or `mvn --batch-mode ...` will do the trick.

*Update*

- The documentation about batch mode see https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.1/maven-embedder/cli.html
- Starting with Maven 3.6.1 (released 2019-04-04) you can use `--no-transfer-progress` will suppress the output of downloading messages at all without suppressing the other output.

Comment: thank you, this did it, can I get rid of downloading/downloaded lines too?

Comment: You can try `mvn -q` but than you will don't see other message as well. May be you can take a look [here](http://maven.apache.org/maven-logging.html).

Comment: mvn --batch-mode ... | grep -v 'Download.* http://'  is what I sometimes use to get rid of the download* messages.

Comment: Does it work for all versions of maven? It seems in my case (version 2.0.4), maven still print ugly "downloaded..." lines regardless adding -B flag.

Comment: Seems pretty well documented to me... https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/non-interactive-release.html

Comment: @Barett the link you provided is only documentation of the release-plugin. It does not mention at all how `--batch-mode` affects output.

Comment: This solution suppresses upload messages as well as downloads, which is usually not desired in a `deploy` task

Comment: @Hilikus The usage of `--no-transfer-progress` will suppress the output by default. In case of errors they will be shown. Apart from that I don't understand the relationship to `deploy`? Where is the difference to download?

Comment: the question is asking specifically about suppressing download noise, which is very verbose with maven. My point is that your solution has an unintended side-effect: It also disables upload logs in the deploy plugin so for example you can't see to which repo you *really* deployed your artifacts

Comment: Maven 3.6.2: -B wasn't sufficient for me, but -ntp did suppress all the "Downloading / Downloaded" messages indeed

Answer (score 88):

First of all, as already answered by khmarbaise, you should use `mvn -B` to enable batch mode.

If you want also to get rid of the "Downloading/Downloaded" lines you can set the corresponding logger `org.apache.maven.cli.transfer.Slf4jMavenTransferListener` to a level higher than info. Therefore I used the `org.slf4j.simpleLogger.log` property as documented [here](http://maven.apache.org/maven-logging.html#Configuring_logging).

Using only the command line, you can do this:

```
mvn -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.cli.transfer.Slf4jMavenTransferListener=warn -B ...
```

Or you can use the `MAVEN_OPTS` environment variable as described [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-maven.html#Configuring_Parallel_Artifact_Resolution):

```
export MAVEN_OPTS=-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.cli.transfer.Slf4jMavenTransferListener=warn
```

**Note:** As far as I am aware this only works for maven 3.1 and above.

Comment: This is great.  Can also add ``org.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.cli.transfer.Slf4jMavenTransferListener=warn`` to $MAVEN_HOME/conf/logging/simplelogging.properties, to make it permanent.

Comment: This solution suppresses upload messages as well as downloads, which is usually not desired in a `deploy` task

Comment: It sets the level to WARN so you will still know if there's a problem. But I agree it would be nice to have a separate setting.

Answer (score 64):

Starting with Maven 3.6.1, Maven now has an option to suppress the transfer progress when downloading/uploading in interactive mode.

`mvn --no-transfer-progress ....`

or in short:

`mvn -ntp ... ....`

The full release note can be found here: http://maven.apache.org/docs/3.6.1/release-notes.html

Answer (score 8):

Same as above answers, but you don't need to add options to command line everytime. Just add the lines into file `${maven.projectBasedir}/.mvn/maven.config`:

```
--no-transfer-progress
```

Then you can use `mvn` as was:

```
mvn test
mvn deploy
```

Answer (score 4):

Quick answer, use maven batch mode, add following to your maven command:

```
-B -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.cli.transfer.Slf4jMavenTransferListener=warn
```

For example:

```
mvn deploy -B -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.cli.transfer.Slf4jMavenTransferListener=warn
```

Answer (score 2):

The only ***useful*** way to suppress downloading/downloaded messages is as follows:

```
mvn --batch-mode ... bla bla bla ... | grep -v 'Download.* http'
```

It is the only useful way because it does not suppress anything else, i.e. the uploading/uploaded [INFO] messages, which anyone in their right mind would want to keep.

Comment: Good point. And I'd feel better making it more specific: ... egrep -v 'INFO.*Download.* from '

Answer (score 0):

I am using apache-maven-3.8.6. Adding --no-transfer-progress option to mvn works for me:

mvn --no-transfer-progress clean install