# Jenkins: too many logs when maven deploy called

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, maven-deploy-plugin

In jenkins log, there are too many logs when maven plugin maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy is called.

For example, when I try to upload a 50MB war to Nexus, there are:

```
Uploading: ...
2/51018 KB
4/51018 KB
6/51018 KB
...
25412/51018 KB
...
51018/51018 KB
Uploaded: ...
```

There is a line for each 2 KB, in this example there are 51018/2 = 25509 lines !

How to configure jenkins (or maven) to only have the upload status like :

```
Uploading: ...
51018/51018 KB
Uploaded: ...
```

Comment: Add `--batch-mode` or the abbreviated variant `-B` to your maven command.

Comment: It works! thanks. I fount another answer about this point here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/21638827/779338

Comment: @khmarbaise thanks for the solution, you should post your solution as an answer so it can get accepted by Nelson G. !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add `--batch-mode` or the abbreviated variant `-B` to your maven command.