# Turn off download messages in Jenkins Console

Tags: jenkins, console-output

I keep getting the following in the Jenkins console output (when dependent jars are being downloaded)

```
[..snip..]

116/599 KB   1512/1884 KB   1451/5488 KB   3268/4455 KB   
116/599 KB   1512/1884 KB   1455/5488 KB   3268/4455 KB   
116/599 KB   1512/1884 KB   1459/5488 KB   3268/4455 KB   
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar (307 KB at 88.2 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/javax/transaction/javax.transaction-api/1.2/javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar
```

How do I fix the job created in Jenkins so the KB info is not shown?

TIA

**Update**
Followed video as well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j3gEgh44iQQ

Added the following to Maven build area under Jenkins (it seems to have worked)
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [disable maven download progress indication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21638697/disable-maven-download-progress-indication)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Maven's batch mode by adding `-B` or `--batch-mode`.

> ```
>  $ mvn -h
>  ...
>  -B,--batch-mode     Run in non-interactive (batch)
>                      mode (disables output color)
> ```

Comment: thanks for the info! How would I change the Jenkins job so that the mvn options (i.e. "-b") can be passed to the mvn call? TIA

Comment: Depends on how the job is defined. Ask your colleague.

Comment: OK - added the flag to Jenkins build area (as seen in update) - it seems to be working (although taking longer) TIA

Comment: what does "don't believe" mean? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I see no reason that your build takes longer because of the batch mode.