# Stop logging downloads for maven repository in gradle build

Tags: maven, gradle, logging, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

On the command line for a maven build [we can specify the argument -ntp (no transfer progress) to stop showing download progress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21638697/disable-maven-download-progress-indication)

Can I do this with a gradle build using a maven repository - is there anything I can add to this part of the build.gradle file for example?

```
repositories {
   mavenCentral()
}
```

Example of logging I would like to avoid:

```
Download
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/beam/beam-sdks-java-core/2.15.0/beam-sdks-java-core-2.15.0.pom
Download
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/cloud/google-cloud-bigquery/1.96.0/google-cloud-bigquery-1.96.0.pom
...
```

Thank you!